# dual boot ubuntu with windows 10 on hp pavillion ab219tx

Tags: hp

> I bought this new HP laptop which is shipped with windows 10.  so I am thinking to do a dual boot with windows 10 and Ubuntu . can Ubuntu work properly on HP?

Comment: Am not sure about your SD card reader. It might not work but apart from that everything should work out of the box.

Comment: He didn't ask about the installation process. He asked whether his system would support Ubuntu or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I checked the hardware specifications and can tell you:

Yes – Ubuntu will run great on this machine.

After installing Ubuntu I recommend to install the latest current stable NVIDIA graphics driver.

You can do this by executing the following commands :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-355 nvidia-prime
sudo reboot
```

Comment: You should a the installation instructions for the PPA.